# Adding Contact Name to Android

Tags: android, contacts

I am using the following code:

```
ArrayList<ContentValues> data = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();

      ContentValues name = new ContentValues();
      name.put(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
      name.put(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, "first name");
      name.put(StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, "last name");
      data.add(name);

      ContentValues row2 = new ContentValues();
      row2.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
      row2.put(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_CUSTOM);
      row2.put(Email.LABEL, "Green Bot");
      row2.put(Email.ADDRESS, "android@android.com");
      data.add(row2);

      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
      intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Insert.DATA, data);

      startActivity(intent);
```

However, only the email is added. The name fields are set empty.

**Update:**
Same goes for the address!

```
ContentValues address = new ContentValues();
      address.put(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
      address.put(StructuredPostal.CITY, "Nasr City");
      address.put(StructuredPostal.COUNTRY, "Egypt");
      address.put(StructuredPostal.REGION, "Cairo");
      address.put(StructuredPostal.TYPE, StructuredPostal.TYPE_WORK);
      data.add(address);
```

Email, phone number, website, IM and photo works fine.

Comment: I posted a bug report for this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=193804

Answer (score 0):

Try this

// Add to contact

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
            .build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    Name)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME,
                    FirstName)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME,
                    LastName).build());

    try {
        ContentProviderResult[] personid = getContentResolver().applyBatch(
                ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I believe this requires a permission to add contact, and I don't want that. My solution doesn't require this permission since the activity appears to the user. Also, this doesn't answer why the name doesn't appear.

Comment: Yes,it requires a permission to add contact.i hope the above answer not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

at last I added extra 'extra's to the intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Insert.DATA, data);
intent.putExtra(Intents.Insert.POSTAL, "addrees");
intent.putExtra(Intents.Insert.NAME, "name");
startActivity(intent);
```

it worked for me. Only for just add name, but i couldn't add firstname, lastname etc.